# How to get the data for restricted site using JSOUP or any programming language

Tags: java, html

This code works fine for unrestricted sites. what are the changes to be done for restricted websites. Here is the restricted link.

http://www.manta.com/c/mrl70cq/geico

```
public class Scrape1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.manta.com/c/mrl70cq/geico").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String text = doc.html();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Here is my error :

when i am running the above code with any URL it getting the whole data from the page. When i am using the following URL **manta.com/c/mrl70cq/geico** i am getting the following error: You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running
Any suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by restricted

Comment: when i am running the above code with any URL it getting the whole data from the page. When i am using the following URL http://www.manta.com/c/mrl70cq/geico i am getting the following error: <body class="block-page"> 
 You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running </body>

Comment: Try touse ui4j or Selenium here.